# How to pass an array of HashMaps to partial

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm building an app with Java and Thymeleaf and I need to pass a HashMap to a partial. I don't want to pass it from a controller.

This is what I tried so far:

user.html

```
<div th:replace="partials/icons.html :: icons(icons=${ {name='user', title='User'}, {name='blog', title='Blog'} })"></div>
```

/partials/icons.html

```
<div th:fragment="icons">
    <th:block th:each="icon : ${icons}">
        <button th:class="'icon-' + ${icon.name}" th:text="${icon.title}"></button>
    </th:block>
</div>
```

It gives me an error that `=` is unexpected. What would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: I should have clarified up-front: there is no way to do what you are trying to do with the syntax of [fragment parameters](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#parameterizable-fragment-signatures). My approach below is a work-around.*

Assuming you have the following object as a starting point:

```
public class Icon {

    private String name;
    private String title;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

Assuming you then have a `List` of such objects, called `icons`...

This list is passed to your Thymeleaf renderer in the usual way. I don't use Spring, so how you do that is (I assume) through an annotation. I may be wrong - it shouldn't affect the approach below, however. In my no-Spring approach the list is added to the Thymeleaf model as `map.put("icons", icons);`

I have the following in my parent Thymeleaf template:

```
<div th:replace = "/iconsfragment.html :: icons(iconlist='icons')">
</div>
```

I have the following in `iconsfragment.html`:

```
<div th:fragment="icons(iconlist)">
    <th:block th:each="icon : ${__${iconlist}__}">
        <div th:class="'icon-' + ${icon.name}" th:text="${icon.title}"></div>
    </th:block>
</div>
```

It uses a preprocessor `__${...}__` to convert the parameter (a string) back into an iterable object.

The resulting HTML that you care about is:

```
<div class="icon-firstName">firstTitle</div>

<div class="icon-secondName">secondTitle</div>
```

This only really makes sense if you want to re-use that fragment in various different ways, of course.  Otherwise just pass the `${icons}` object directly to the fragment.

And my `<div>` example would of course need to be adapted to your `<button>` example.